# Unable to run Windows updated or shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-11

I recently had an issue, where I was formatting an old SSD, where I had Linux installed.
Afterwards I remembered, that when I was installing Linux on it, the bootloader or something was moved to that SSD, which was necessary for GRUB to work or something (can't recall what the issue was, because it's so long ago).

To fix  the issue, I essentially followed [this Guides Method 2 - Part 1](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/accidentally-deleted-boot-partition-windows-10.html#toc.0.9683402256624305), which essentially tells you to create a new boot partition and how to set it up:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk n 
list partition
create partition efi
format quick fs=fat32
list partition

bcdboot C:\windows /s Y:
```

So I created a new partition with 101MB and followed the instructions and everything appeared to be fine.

I'm not really sure if my two problems are related with this, but it happened all in the past two weeks so I deemed it worth mentioning.

**1. Issue**

I'm not sure why this is happening now and I can't recall if it just happened after the fix or shortly after, but when I try to Shut down windows, I immediately get thrown back to the login screen.
I saw some people saying that disabling fast boot could fix the issue, but I want to resolve the underlying issue, also I want to keep fast boot on.

**2. Issue**

I got some windows Updates, now if I hit restart/shutdown my computer to install them, the installation process starts, but after it finishes I get the following error:

> Something didn't go as planned. No need to worry- undoing changes.
> Please keep your computer on.

I also checked the Event Viewer and found the following Error:

> Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update
> with error 0x800F0922: 2023-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 11
> Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5030219).

---

I really hope there is a way to fix this, because currently I have to forcefully shut down my by and not being able to install updates is also not sustainable.

If possible I really want to avoid having to reinstall Windows, because setting everything up afterwards and backing everything up is always a real pain.

Comment: Reinstalling Wind0ws is probably the best solution tho. Also, its Grub not Grup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB

Comment: ... and the error 0x800F0922 has nothing to do with Grub or dual-booting anyway.

Comment: Yea I'm wondering if they issues are even related with the deleted/new boot partition. But I can't really think of anything else which I could have done causing the issue.

Comment: Yea reinstalling would be the easiest solution for the issues, but then I have to back up everything, get a drive to backup everything to it or deal with potential data loss and having to setup everything, which probably alone takes at least a day to get the basic setup running. That's what I'm trying to avoid - but I don't want to go for some hacky solution which in the long run may cause some issues.

Comment: Not just the easiest; probably also the best solution. I agree that it sucks.

Comment: Lesson learned then: Yo should have backups regardless. Backups are done to prevent problems of data loss, not something yo do when something wrong happened.

Comment: First of all I do have backups. Also it's not necessarily only about the backups, it's more about the time it takes to get a system up and running and fully configured and there are some projects which alone take a few hours to build and there is always a script, some other files which might be missing, except if you have a few TB of backups. But not the topic anyway ,,,

Comment: And of course reinstalling the system will fix the problem, I was just wondering how to fix the underlying problem, since reinstalling is a last resort! Thanks for your input.